Tengo el siguiente error la primera vez que entro a la consola de AWS
Este error "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1" me sale la primera vez que entro a la consola de AWS. Es una cuenta recién creada y no se ha usado para nada. Este error tampoco me permite crear usuarios y a su vez tampoco generar las credenciales.

